# how to split a string using an "%" using a for loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I have an app and I want to have it take CMD's but its a 3 part CMD.

for example "1307%launchApp%n/a".

that's a 3 part cmd pass%cmd%additionalInfo split with %'s

how would i take that and store it in 3 different Strings?

```
String Pass;
String CMD;
String AdditionalInfo;
```

I do be leave to use a For Loop, but I would like to know how to implant it and why it works so that i could use it in different projects

THANK YOU!!

let me know if you need a better explanation or more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use a for loop as you can us inbuilt method `split` as:

```
 String sample = "1307%launchApp%n/a";
    String[] result = sample.split("%");
    String pass = result[0];
    String cmd = result[1];
    String additionalInfo = result[2];
    System.out.println("pass: " + pass + " CMD: " + cmd + " Addtional Info: " + additionalInfo);
```

It prints:

`pass: 1307 CMD: launchApp Addtional Info: n/a`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to split it

```
String string = "1307%launchApp%n/a";
String[] parts = string.split("%");
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need for loop. Try,

```
String commandString = "pass%cmd%additionalInfo";
String[] commands = commandString.split("%");
String firstCommand = commands[0];
....
```